# Null pointer after implementing custom events, have no idea what's missing

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

This is only my second question on here so please bear with me if I'm doing anything wrong.

I have been coding a Bukkit plugin that includes a radiation effect, where if you aren't in a designated safezone you get damaged. I am using the WorldEdit API to designate said zones, but am now receiving a null pointer after implementing the damaging effect itself.

Here is the radiation class:

```
package com.psychoticatt.outerrimcore;


import java.util.HashMap;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;

import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerMoveEvent;
import org.bukkit.potion.PotionEffect;
import org.bukkit.potion.PotionEffectType;

import com.psychoticatt.outerrimcore.events.PlayerIrradiatedEvent;
import com.sk89q.worldedit.bukkit.BukkitAdapter;
import com.sk89q.worldedit.math.BlockVector3;
import com.sk89q.worldedit.regions.CuboidRegion;
import com.sk89q.worldedit.world.World;

public class Radiation implements Listener {
    
    public org.bukkit.World waste = Bukkit.getServer().getWorld("wasteland");
    public World w = BukkitAdapter.adapt(waste);
    
    Location loc1 = new Location(waste, 207, 3, 124);
    Location loc2 = new Location(waste, 226, 23, 143);
    
    BlockVector3 vect1 = BukkitAdapter.asBlockVector(loc1);
    BlockVector3 vect2 = BukkitAdapter.asBlockVector(loc2);
    
    CuboidRegion cRegion1 = new CuboidRegion(w, vect1, vect2);
    
    PotionEffect rStage1 = new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.WITHER, 1, 10000, false, false, true);
    PotionEffect rStage2 = new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.WITHER, 2, 1000000, false, false, true);
    
    HashMap<Player, Boolean> radStatus = new HashMap<Player, Boolean>();
    
    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerMove(PlayerMoveEvent e) {

        Player p = (Player) e.getPlayer();

        BlockVector3 to = BukkitAdapter.asBlockVector(e.getTo());
        BlockVector3 from = BukkitAdapter.asBlockVector(e.getFrom());

        if(cRegion1.contains(to) && !cRegion1.contains(from)) {

            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Entering Safezone!");
            PlayerIrradiatedEvent isIrradiated = new PlayerIrradiatedEvent(p, false);
            Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().callEvent(isIrradiated);

        } else if(!cRegion1.contains(to) && cRegion1.contains(from)) {

            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Exiting Safezone, You Are Exposed To " + ChatColor.GREEN + "Radiation!");

            PlayerIrradiatedEvent isIrradiated = new PlayerIrradiatedEvent(p, true);
            Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().callEvent(isIrradiated);
        }
    }
    
    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
        Player p = (Player) e.getPlayer();
        radStatus.put(p, false);
    }
    
    @EventHandler
    public void onIrradiated(PlayerIrradiatedEvent e) throws InterruptedException {
        Player p = (Player) e.getPlayer();
        Boolean s = e.getStatus();

        if(radStatus.containsKey(p)) {

            radStatus.replace(p, s);

            if(radStatus.get(p).equals(true)) {

                p.addPotionEffect(rStage1);
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                p.addPotionEffect(rStage2);

            } else {

                p.removePotionEffect(PotionEffectType.WITHER);

            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Here is the custom event I reference:

```
package com.psychoticatt.outerrimcore.events;

import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.Event;
import org.bukkit.event.HandlerList;

public class PlayerIrradiatedEvent extends Event {
    
    private Player player;
    private Boolean status;
    
    public PlayerIrradiatedEvent(Player p, boolean b) {
        player = p;
        status = b;
    }
    
    public Boolean getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    
    public Player getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }
    
    public HandlerList getHandlers() {
        return null;
    }
    
}
```

My main class:

```
package com.psychoticatt.outerrimcore;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
    
    public void onEnable() {
        this.getServer().getLogger().info("[OuterRimCore] Works!");
        
        Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new Radiation(), this);
    }
}
```

And here is the error log:

```
[03:57:18] [main/INFO]: Environment: authHost='https://authserver.mojang.com', accountsHost='https://api.mojang.com', sessionHost='https://sessionserver.mojang.com', name='PROD'
[03:57:19] [main/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default, bukkit
[03:57:19] [Worker-Main-14/INFO]: Loaded 7 recipes
[03:57:22] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting minecraft server version 1.16.2
[03:57:22] [Server thread/INFO]: Loading properties
[03:57:24] [Server thread/INFO]: This server is running CraftBukkit version git-Spigot-b5a13e6-3980640 (MC: 1.16.2) (Implementing API version 1.16.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT)
[03:57:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Debug logging is disabled
[03:57:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Server Ping Player Sample Count: 12
[03:57:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Using 4 threads for Netty based IO
[03:57:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Default game type: SURVIVAL
[03:57:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair
[03:57:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting Minecraft server on *:25565
[03:57:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Using default channel type
[03:57:27] [Server thread/WARN]: Initializing Legacy Material Support. Unless you have legacy plugins and/or data this is a bug!
[03:57:32] [Server thread/WARN]: Legacy plugin OuterRimCore v0.1 does not specify an api-version.
[03:57:32] [Server thread/INFO]: [WorldEdit] Loading WorldEdit v7.1.0;8e55131
[03:57:33] [Server thread/INFO]: Got request to register class com.sk89q.worldedit.bukkit.BukkitServerInterface with WorldEdit [com.sk89q.worldedit.extension.platform.PlatformManager@3a33813c]
[03:57:33] [Server thread/INFO]: [OuterRimCore] Loading OuterRimCore v0.1
[03:57:33] [Server thread/INFO]: [Essentials] Loading Essentials v2.18.1.3
[03:57:33] [Server thread/INFO]: [EssentialsSpawn] Loading EssentialsSpawn v2.18.1.3
[03:57:33] [Server thread/INFO]: [Multiverse-Core] Loading Multiverse-Core v4.1.0-b775
[03:57:33] [Server thread/INFO]: [WorldEdit] Enabling WorldEdit v7.1.0;8e55131
[03:57:33] [Server thread/INFO]: WEPIF: Using the Bukkit Permissions API.
[03:57:34] [Server thread/WARN]: 
**********************************************
** This WorldEdit version does not fully support your version of Bukkit.
**
** When working with blocks or undoing, chests will be empty, signs
** will be blank, and so on. There will be no support for entity
** and block property-related functions.
**
** Please see https://worldedit.enginehub.org/en/latest/faq/#bukkit-adapters
**********************************************

[03:57:35] [Server thread/WARN]: [WorldEdit] ====================================================
[03:57:35] [Server thread/WARN]: [WorldEdit]  WorldEdit works better if you use Paper 
[03:57:35] [Server thread/WARN]: [WorldEdit]  as your server software. 
[03:57:35] [Server thread/WARN]: [WorldEdit]   
[03:57:35] [Server thread/WARN]: [WorldEdit]  Paper offers significant performance improvements,
[03:57:35] [Server thread/WARN]: [WorldEdit]  bug fixes, security enhancements and optional
[03:57:35] [Server thread/WARN]: [WorldEdit]  features for server owners to enhance their server.
[03:57:35] [Server thread/WARN]: [WorldEdit]   
[03:57:35] [Server thread/WARN]: [WorldEdit]  Paper includes Timings v2, which is significantly
[03:57:35] [Server thread/WARN]: [WorldEdit]  better at diagnosing lag problems over v1.
[03:57:35] [Server thread/WARN]: [WorldEdit]   
[03:57:35] [Server thread/WARN]: [WorldEdit]  All of your plugins should still work, and the
[03:57:35] [Server thread/WARN]: [WorldEdit]  Paper community will gladly help you fix any issues.
[03:57:35] [Server thread/WARN]: [WorldEdit]   
[03:57:35] [Server thread/WARN]: [WorldEdit]  Join the Paper Community @ https://papermc.io
[03:57:35] [Server thread/WARN]: [WorldEdit] ====================================================
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing level "world"
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: -------- World Settings For [world] --------
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Allow Zombie Pigmen to spawn from portal blocks: true
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Item Despawn Rate: 6000
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Item Merge Radius: 2.5
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: View Distance: 10
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Entity Tracking Range: Pl 48 / An 48 / Mo 48 / Mi 32 / Other 64
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Tile Max Tick Time: 50ms Entity max Tick Time: 50ms
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Max TNT Explosions: 100
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Arrow Despawn Rate: 1200 Trident Respawn Rate:1200
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Nerfing mobs spawned from spawners: false
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Zombie Aggressive Towards Villager: true
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Custom Map Seeds:  Village: 10387312 Desert: 14357617 Igloo: 14357618 Jungle: 14357619 Swamp: 14357620 Monument: 10387313 Ocean: 14357621 Shipwreck: 165745295 End City: 10387313 Slime: 987234911 Bastion: 30084232 Fortress: 30084232 Mansion: 10387319 Fossil: 14357921 Portal: 34222645
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Hopper Transfer: 8 Hopper Check: 1 Hopper Amount: 1
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Experience Merge Radius: 3.0
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Cactus Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Cane Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Melon Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Mushroom Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Pumpkin Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Sapling Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Beetroot Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Carrot Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Potato Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Wheat Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: NetherWart Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Vine Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Cocoa Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Bamboo Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: SweetBerry Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Kelp Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Mob Spawn Range: 6
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Entity Activation Range: An 32 / Mo 32 / Ra 48 / Mi 16 / Tiv true
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Registering commands with com.sk89q.worldedit.bukkit.BukkitServerInterface
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: -------- World Settings For [world_nether] --------
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Allow Zombie Pigmen to spawn from portal blocks: true
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Item Despawn Rate: 6000
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Item Merge Radius: 2.5
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: View Distance: 10
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Entity Tracking Range: Pl 48 / An 48 / Mo 48 / Mi 32 / Other 64
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Tile Max Tick Time: 50ms Entity max Tick Time: 50ms
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Max TNT Explosions: 100
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Arrow Despawn Rate: 1200 Trident Respawn Rate:1200
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Nerfing mobs spawned from spawners: false
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Zombie Aggressive Towards Villager: true
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Custom Map Seeds:  Village: 10387312 Desert: 14357617 Igloo: 14357618 Jungle: 14357619 Swamp: 14357620 Monument: 10387313 Ocean: 14357621 Shipwreck: 165745295 End City: 10387313 Slime: 987234911 Bastion: 30084232 Fortress: 30084232 Mansion: 10387319 Fossil: 14357921 Portal: 34222645
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Hopper Transfer: 8 Hopper Check: 1 Hopper Amount: 1
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Experience Merge Radius: 3.0
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Cactus Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Cane Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Melon Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Mushroom Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Pumpkin Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Sapling Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Beetroot Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Carrot Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Potato Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Wheat Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: NetherWart Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Vine Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Cocoa Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Bamboo Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: SweetBerry Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Kelp Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Mob Spawn Range: 6
[03:57:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Entity Activation Range: An 32 / Mo 32 / Ra 48 / Mi 16 / Tiv true
[03:57:36] [Server thread/INFO]: -------- World Settings For [world_the_end] --------
[03:57:36] [Server thread/INFO]: Allow Zombie Pigmen to spawn from portal blocks: true
[03:57:36] [Server thread/INFO]: Item Despawn Rate: 6000
[03:57:36] [Server thread/INFO]: Item Merge Radius: 2.5
[03:57:36] [Server thread/INFO]: View Distance: 10
[03:57:36] [Server thread/INFO]: Entity Tracking Range: Pl 48 / An 48 / Mo 48 / Mi 32 / Other 64
[03:57:36] [Server thread/INFO]: Tile Max Tick Time: 50ms Entity max Tick Time: 50ms
[03:57:36] [Server thread/INFO]: Max TNT Explosions: 100
[03:57:36] [Server thread/INFO]: Arrow Despawn Rate: 1200 Trident Respawn Rate:1200
[03:57:36] [Server thread/INFO]: Nerfing mobs spawned from spawners: false
[03:57:36] [Server thread/INFO]: Zombie Aggressive Towards Villager: true
[03:57:36] [Server thread/INFO]: Custom Map Seeds:  Village: 10387312 Desert: 14357617 Igloo: 14357618 Jungle: 14357619 Swamp: 14357620 Monument: 10387313 Ocean: 14357621 Shipwreck: 165745295 End City: 10387313 Slime: 987234911 Bastion: 30084232 Fortress: 30084232 Mansion: 10387319 Fossil: 14357921 Portal: 34222645
[03:57:36] [Server thread/INFO]: Hopper Transfer: 8 Hopper Check: 1 Hopper Amount: 1
[03:57:36] [Server thread/INFO]: Experience Merge Radius: 3.0
[03:57:36] [Server thread/INFO]: Cactus Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:36] [Server thread/INFO]: Cane Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:36] [Server thread/INFO]: Melon Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:36] [Server thread/INFO]: Mushroom Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:36] [Server thread/INFO]: Pumpkin Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:36] [Server thread/INFO]: Sapling Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:36] [Server thread/INFO]: Beetroot Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:36] [Server thread/INFO]: Carrot Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:36] [Server thread/INFO]: Potato Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:36] [Server thread/INFO]: Wheat Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:36] [Server thread/INFO]: NetherWart Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:36] [Server thread/INFO]: Vine Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:36] [Server thread/INFO]: Cocoa Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:36] [Server thread/INFO]: Bamboo Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:36] [Server thread/INFO]: SweetBerry Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:36] [Server thread/INFO]: Kelp Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:36] [Server thread/INFO]: Mob Spawn Range: 6
[03:57:36] [Server thread/INFO]: Entity Activation Range: An 32 / Mo 32 / Ra 48 / Mi 16 / Tiv true
[03:57:36] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing start region for dimension minecraft:overworld
[03:57:38] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0%
[03:57:38] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0%
[03:57:38] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0%
[03:57:38] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0%
[03:57:38] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0%
[03:57:38] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0%
[03:57:42] [Worker-Main-9/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 83%
[03:57:42] [Worker-Main-8/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 83%
[03:57:42] [Worker-Main-17/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 83%
[03:57:42] [Worker-Main-8/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 83%
[03:57:42] [Worker-Main-10/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 83%
[03:57:42] [Worker-Main-11/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 83%
[03:57:42] [Worker-Main-11/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 83%
[03:57:42] [Worker-Main-11/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 83%
[03:57:43] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 83%
[03:57:43] [Worker-Main-11/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 88%
[03:57:44] [Worker-Main-11/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 88%
[03:57:44] [Worker-Main-10/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 88%
[03:57:45] [Worker-Main-10/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 93%
[03:57:45] [Server thread/INFO]: Time elapsed: 9382 ms
[03:57:45] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing start region for dimension minecraft:the_nether
[03:57:46] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0%
[03:57:46] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0%
[03:57:46] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0%
[03:57:46] [Worker-Main-8/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 83%
[03:57:47] [Worker-Main-10/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 83%
[03:57:47] [Worker-Main-16/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 83%
[03:57:48] [Worker-Main-9/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 89%
[03:57:48] [Worker-Main-10/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 98%
[03:57:49] [Server thread/INFO]: Time elapsed: 3586 ms
[03:57:49] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing start region for dimension minecraft:the_end
[03:57:49] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0%
[03:57:49] [Worker-Main-10/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 83%
[03:57:49] [Server thread/INFO]: Time elapsed: 729 ms
[03:57:49] [Server thread/INFO]: [OuterRimCore] Enabling OuterRimCore v0.1
[03:57:49] [Server thread/INFO]: [OuterRimCore] Works!
[03:57:49] [Server thread/WARN]: [OuterRimCore] Loaded class com.sk89q.worldedit.bukkit.BukkitAdapter from WorldEdit v7.1.0;8e55131 which is not a depend, softdepend or loadbefore of this plugin.
[03:57:49] [Server thread/ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling OuterRimCore v0.1 (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:770) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-3980640]
    at com.sk89q.worldedit.bukkit.BukkitAdapter.adapt(BukkitAdapter.java:120) ~[?:?]
    at com.psychoticatt.outerrimcore.Radiation.<init>(Radiation.java:27) ~[?:?]
    at com.psychoticatt.outerrimcore.Main.onEnable(Main.java:11) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:263) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-3980640]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:351) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-3980640]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:480) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-3980640]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R2.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:492) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-3980640]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R2.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:406) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-3980640]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.loadWorld(MinecraftServer.java:435) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-3980640]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:219) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-3980640]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:808) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-3980640]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:164) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-b5a13e6-3980640]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_261]
[03:57:49] [Server thread/INFO]: [Essentials] Enabling Essentials v2.18.1.3
[03:57:49] [Server thread/INFO]: Attempting to convert old kits in config.yml to new kits.yml
[03:57:49] [Server thread/INFO]: No kits found to migrate.
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Loaded 25599 items from items.json.
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Using locale en_US
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: [Essentials] ServerListPingEvent: Spigot iterator API
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: [Essentials] Starting Metrics. Opt-out using the global bStats config.
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: [Essentials] Using superperms-based permissions.
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: [EssentialsSpawn] Enabling EssentialsSpawn v2.18.1.3
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: [EssentialsSpawn] Starting Metrics. Opt-out using the global bStats config.
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: [Multiverse-Core] Enabling Multiverse-Core v4.1.0-b775
[03:57:50] [Server thread/WARN]: [Multiverse-Core] "Multiverse-Core v4.1.0-b775" has registered a listener for org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityCreatePortalEvent on method "public void com.onarandombox.MultiverseCore.listeners.MVPortalListener.entityPortalCreate(org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityCreatePortalEvent)", but the event is Deprecated. "Server performance will be affected"; please notify the authors [Rigby, fernferret, lithium3141, main--, dumptruckman].
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: [Multiverse-Core] We are aware of the warning about the deprecated event. There is no alternative that allows us to do what we need to do. The performance impact is negligible.
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: -------- World Settings For [wasteland] --------
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Allow Zombie Pigmen to spawn from portal blocks: true
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Item Despawn Rate: 6000
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Item Merge Radius: 2.5
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: View Distance: 10
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Entity Tracking Range: Pl 48 / An 48 / Mo 48 / Mi 32 / Other 64
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Tile Max Tick Time: 50ms Entity max Tick Time: 50ms
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Max TNT Explosions: 100
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Arrow Despawn Rate: 1200 Trident Respawn Rate:1200
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Nerfing mobs spawned from spawners: false
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Zombie Aggressive Towards Villager: true
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Custom Map Seeds:  Village: 10387312 Desert: 14357617 Igloo: 14357618 Jungle: 14357619 Swamp: 14357620 Monument: 10387313 Ocean: 14357621 Shipwreck: 165745295 End City: 10387313 Slime: 987234911 Bastion: 30084232 Fortress: 30084232 Mansion: 10387319 Fossil: 14357921 Portal: 34222645
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Hopper Transfer: 8 Hopper Check: 1 Hopper Amount: 1
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Experience Merge Radius: 3.0
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Cactus Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Cane Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Melon Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Mushroom Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Pumpkin Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Sapling Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Beetroot Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Carrot Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Potato Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Wheat Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: NetherWart Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Vine Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Cocoa Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Bamboo Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: SweetBerry Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Kelp Growth Modifier: 100%
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Mob Spawn Range: 6
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Entity Activation Range: An 32 / Mo 32 / Ra 48 / Mi 16 / Tiv true
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing start region for dimension minecraft:wasteland
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0%
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Time elapsed: 381 ms
[03:57:50] [Server thread/INFO]: [Multiverse-Core] 4 - World(s) loaded.
[03:57:51] [Server thread/INFO]: [Multiverse-Core] Version 4.1.0-b775 (API v24) Enabled - By Rigby, fernferret, lithium3141, main-- and dumptruckman
[03:57:51] [Server thread/INFO]: [Multiverse-Core] Help dumptruckman keep this project alive. Become a patron! https://www.patreon.com/dumptruckman
[03:57:51] [Server thread/INFO]: [Multiverse-Core] One time donations are also appreciated: https://www.paypal.me/dumptruckman
[03:57:51] [Server thread/INFO]: Server permissions file permissions.yml is empty, ignoring it
[03:57:51] [Server thread/INFO]: Done (16.310s)! For help, type "help"
[03:57:53] [Server thread/INFO]: Stopping server
[03:57:53] [Server thread/INFO]: [Multiverse-Core] Disabling Multiverse-Core v4.1.0-b775
[03:57:53] [Server thread/INFO]: [EssentialsSpawn] Disabling EssentialsSpawn v2.18.1.3
[03:57:53] [Server thread/INFO]: [Essentials] Disabling Essentials v2.18.1.3
[03:57:53] [Server thread/INFO]: [OuterRimCore] Disabling OuterRimCore v0.1
[03:57:53] [Server thread/INFO]: [WorldEdit] Disabling WorldEdit v7.1.0;8e55131
[03:57:53] [Server thread/INFO]: Unregistering com.sk89q.worldedit.bukkit.BukkitServerInterface from WorldEdit
[03:57:53] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving players
[03:57:54] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving worlds
[03:57:54] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving chunks for level 'ServerLevel[world]'/minecraft:overworld
[03:57:55] [Server thread/INFO]: ThreadedAnvilChunkStorage (world): All chunks are saved
[03:57:55] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving chunks for level 'ServerLevel[world_nether]'/minecraft:the_nether
[03:57:56] [Server thread/INFO]: ThreadedAnvilChunkStorage (DIM-1): All chunks are saved
[03:57:56] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving chunks for level 'ServerLevel[world_the_end]'/minecraft:the_end
[03:57:56] [Server thread/INFO]: ThreadedAnvilChunkStorage (DIM1): All chunks are saved
[03:57:56] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving chunks for level 'ServerLevel[wasteland]'/minecraft:wasteland
[03:57:56] [Server thread/INFO]: ThreadedAnvilChunkStorage (wasteland): All chunks are saved
[03:57:56] [Server thread/INFO]: ThreadedAnvilChunkStorage (world): All chunks are saved
[03:57:56] [Server thread/INFO]: ThreadedAnvilChunkStorage (DIM-1): All chunks are saved
[03:57:56] [Server thread/INFO]: ThreadedAnvilChunkStorage (DIM1): All chunks are saved
[03:57:56] [Server thread/INFO]: ThreadedAnvilChunkStorage (wasteland): All chunks are saved
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, since I can't seem to find a solution anywhere else.

Comment: I suppose that is the line that throws (27): `public World w = BukkitAdapter.adapt(waste);`, right? Have you checked whether `waste` is null?

Comment: Check out https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/this-happens-whenever-the-server-starts-help.71367/ They say that deleting usercache.json helps

Comment: I just ran a quick debug script and no, waste is not null.

Comment: Hmm, your conclussion seems to disagree with `com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull` Maybe you can use your debugger and step into the adapt method and see what is null.

Comment: Alright so I ran a simple script in my PlayerMoveEvent that sends the player a message saying "not null" if w is not null, and vice versa. The strange part is its sending me no message at all, and I know i didn't mess that part up.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

As it turns out, my custom event class was incomplete, and wasn't set to return the event handler. So my onEnable() method in my main class was trying to get all the event handlers and was getting a null value for one of them.

I've included the updated code here:

```
package com.psychoticatt.outerrimcore.events;

import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.Event;
import org.bukkit.event.HandlerList;

public class PlayerIrradiatedEvent extends Event {
    private static final HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
    private Player player;
    private Boolean status;
    
    public PlayerIrradiatedEvent(Player p, boolean b) {
        player = p;
        status = b;
    }
    
    public Boolean getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    
    public Player getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }
    
    public HandlerList getHandlers() {
        return handlers;
    }
    
    public static HandlerList getHandlerList() {
        return handlers;
    }
    
}
```

Thanks to everybody who responded so quickly, you helped me get on the right track!